# Centering content in CSS both supporting IE and chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11, css-grid

I have this Css grid, with grid items, which with chrome can i easilty be centered by applying `justify-items:center` or that kind of magic.

But this solution does not seem to work in IE, it keeps being stuck to the left side.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jjgmNX

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item-2">2</div>
  <div class="item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item-4">4</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
    grid-gap: 20px;
    justify-items: center;
}

.item-1 {
    background-color: rgba(200,520,266,.75);
    border-color: #b4b4b4;
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
}

.item-2 {
    background-color: rgba(145,520,0,.75);
    grid-gap: 20px;
}

.item-3 {
    background-color: rgba(145,520,0,.75);
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 1;
}

.item-4 {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    border-color: transparent;
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
}
```

How do i center the child divs - both supported in IE and chrome ?

Comment: I think IE11 needs the -ms prefix for quite a lot of grid, and not all properties are supported. I'd check out https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid to see what's what.

Answer (score 3):

You can use flexbox instead of grid that has good support on the browsers.

```
.grid-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item-1 {
    flex: 1 1 33.33%;
    background-color: rgba(200,520,266,.75);
    border-color: #b4b4b4;
}

.item-2 {
    flex: 1 1 33.33%;
    background-color: rgba(145,520,0,.75);
}

.item-3 {
    flex: 1 1 33.33%;
    background-color: rgba(145,520,0,.75);
}

.item-4 {
   flex-basis: 33.33%;
   /* important */
   margin: auto;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
   border-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: why is  `margin: auto` important? is moves the item to the last grid position?

Comment: Yes, it's a trick. Here you can use `margin-left: auto' or 'margin-right: auto' that depends on your page direction.

Comment: Ok change the all `flex` and `flex-basis` to `flex: 1`. The container will be divided between the items equally.

Comment: and the width of ìtem2half` should be the same as the one above `item2` and follow when the screen becomes smaller. 
As I see it - the size does not follow?

Comment: item2half didn't have any html tag. what do you want to do? I can't imagine. Draw an image or play with the basis of item2half. For example change to `flex:.5`.

Answer (score 0):

`justify-items` isn't supported in IE for `display: grid`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-items#Support_in_Grid_layout

A tag soup workaround is to have the sub containers with `display:flex`, as `justify-items` is supported for that: or just use flexbox exclusively.