# html and css alignment between chrome and IE11

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11, css-grid

I am currenlty in a situation where I have this html

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
   <div class="item2">
    <div class="item3">3begin</div>
    <div class="item3">3end</div>
   </div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>  
</div>
```

with these stylings

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
    grid-gap: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:nowrap;
}

.item1 {
    background-color: rgba(200,520,266,.75);
    border-color: #b4b4b4;
  flex: 100% 3 1;
}

.item2 {
    background-color: rgba(145,520,0,.75);
    grid-gap: 20px;
    flex: 100% 1 3;
}

.item3 {
    background-color: rgba(145,520,0,.75);
}

.item4 {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    border-color: transparent;
    flex: 100% 3 1;
}
```

which style wise divides the screen into 3 columns, and in the fourth column places the `item4`.

I would like to have `item4` appear between `3begin` and `3end`
without altering the html - only done by styling.

Whats important here is this has to supported both on IE and chrome.

I tried multiple attempts in doing this -  the closest I've gotten so far is

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item3">3begin</div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item3half">3end</div>
</div>
```

with stylings

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
    grid-gap: 20px;
}

.item1 {
    background-color: rgba(200,520,266,.75);
    border-color: #b4b4b4;
}

.item3 {
    background-color: rgba(145,520,0,.75);
}

.item3half {
    background-color: rgba(145,520,0,.75);
   grid-column-start: 2;

}

.item4 {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    border-color: transparent;
   grid-column-start: 2;
}
```

this though only works flawless in chrome - but since grid is not supported in IE, I am bound to use flex, which with inspiration from this [Centering content in CSS both supporting IE and chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57059675/centering-content-in-css-both-supporting-ie-and-chrome)

gave me a good idea on how to incorporate flex for only IE cases - so I began using flex with which i can't seem to solve the issue.

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item3">3begin</div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item3half">3end</div>
</div>


.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
    grid-gap: 20px;
  @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
  }

.item1 {
    background-color: rgba(145,520,0,.75);
    @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none){
      flex: 1 1 33.33%;
    }
}

.item3 {
    background-color: rgba(145,520,0,.75);
    @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none){
      flex: 1 1 33.33%;
    }
}

.item3half {
    background-color: rgba(145,520,0,.75);
   grid-column-start: 2;
   @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none){
      flex-basis: 33.33%;
    }

}

.item4 {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    border-color: transparent;
   grid-column-start: 2;
   @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none){
      flex-basis: 33.33%;
    }
}
```

This does not appear to be the same when comparing IE with chrome?

IE don't have the `4` item under `3begin` oddly placed next to `3end`
and the entire column is not aligned and don't have the same width - how do i fix that?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wVwPPw?editors=1100

Comment: Did you check https://caniuse.com/#search=flex? Check the "Known issues" tab. It seems there are some bugs on IE when using flex-basis

Comment: ahh... shit.. other suggestions how to do it? @Azametzin

Comment: Not really. This is looking harder than it needs to be. I know the situation probably prevents this, but changing the HTML structure would be far more advantageous than all of this.

Comment: @Azametzin but it also say that it is fixed in version 10 or above... i am using IE11

Comment: Try to apply media query like this for IE. _:-ms-fullscreen, :root .CLASS_NAME {property:value;} Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45973976/apply-only-to-ie-11-within-media-query-for-screen-size also try to use this online tool to auto correct your css code https://autoprefixer.github.io/?source=post_page